# Android How can i add some delay on multiple animations?

Tags: android, android-animation

What i want is that each animation, from the code below, to start with a delay, like a sequence. So i have this code:

```
   public void setAnimation(){
        View view;
        String animation = prefs.getString("animations", "Scale");
        String interpolator = prefs.getString("interpolators", "Bounce");
        Animation animate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.scale_in);
        for(int i=0; i<gridView.getChildCount(); i++){
            view = gridView.getChildAt(i);

            view.startAnimation(animate);
        }
    }
```

because there is a for loop, all child animations will start instantly. I already tried with:

```
Thread.sleep....
Handler...
animate.setStartTime...
animate.setStartOffset...
```

but all child animations starts instantly.

I tried this method inside of loop, and the animations won't start:

```
animate.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
        view.startAnimation(animate);
    }

    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
    }

    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
    }

});
```

Thanx in advance.

Comment: add an animation listener, and when one animation finished start the next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create a GridLayoutAnimationController or LayoutAnimationController.

Answer (score 0):

I used **LayoutAnimationController** to show elements in **LinearLayout** with animation effect one by one using following code.

```
     Animation fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.anim_fade_in);
//lnrContactContainer is LinearLayout.
            AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
            set.addAnimation(fadeIn);
            set.setDuration(500);
            controller = new LayoutAnimationController(set, 1f);
            lnrContactContainer.setLayoutAnimation(controller);          
            lnrContactContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

But same approach does not work when I use it to show fadeout animation while hiding **LinearLayout** `lnrContactContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE)`;