# How to start a second animation after the first animation finishes

Tags: java, android, xml, animation

I have created two animations for two images and it's working fine but I would like the second animation to start when the first animations finishes.

The code:

```
package com.example.animatest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class animation001 extends Activity {

    private ImageView image1;
    private ImageView image2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        final Animation animTranslate1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.translate);
        final Animation animTranslate2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.translate2);

        image1.startAnimation(animTranslate1);
        image2.startAnimation(animTranslate2);

    }

}
```

and this is the first animation xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="1500"
        android:repeatCount="0"
        android:repeatMode="reverse" />
</set>
```

and this is the second  animation xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0"
        android:duration="25000"
        android:repeatCount="0"
        android:repeatMode="reverse" />
</set>
```

Comment: Check out the accepted answer at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9341447/867591

Comment: there is no answer for my question there

Comment: He is saying that he isn't going to write the code for you. However, there is good material to problem solve in the link he has provided.

Comment: @Mohammed Asmar have u check my solution

Comment: i am try to do it but i I could not

Comment: can u just add the  solution  into my question

Comment: Hi Asmar! Please go through the tutorial in Dixit's answer..it should point you in the right direction. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it this way & It is works for me.

Just implement `AnimationListener` in Your **Activity**

```
public class animation001 extends Activity implements AnimationListener {
    .........
}
```

follow this [**tutorial**](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/how-to-use-android-animation-listeners/1227) which help you better way to implement **Animation**.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an `AnimationListener` and implement `public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)`.
2. Set this `AnimationListener` to your first animation with `Animation.setAnimationListener()`
3. Start your second animation in `AnimationListener.onAnimationEnd()`